# "Ignoring query to other database" Command line

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this weird message, while executing **any** query in command prompt `MySQL`.

```
ignoring query to other database
```

I have already tried changing the database by issuing the `"use database_name"` command.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Ok, It seems, I had missed the "u" flag for user so accidentally I had input the following command.

```
mysql -root -p // Faulty connection
```

Instead of ...

```
mysql -uroot -p // Correct connection
```

Notice the missing "u" from the Faulty connection.

Comment: Using "mysql -u root -p" with a space after u brought me to this question :)

Comment: @sr9yar I think, the whitespace after `-u` flag should'nt be a problem. Are you sure *that* was the issue? as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636160/mysql-connection-whitespace-after-user-flag

Comment: yes its true. the space has no issue. you either use -uroot or -u root

Comment: Apparently the same problem exists when you use `-U` instead of `-u`.