# mysql connection whitespace after user flag

Tags: mysql, command-line, console

I have a question, What is the significance of the **whitespace** after the user flag `-u` inside a mysql connection string?

```
mysql -u myname -pmypass mydb
```

I mean to say, the above command works just fine, if I don't pass a whitespace after `-u` and just write the above command as below.

```
mysql -umyname -pmypass mydb
```

I tried searching for an explaination by using the following search terms.

- `mysql login whitespace after user flag`
- `mysql connection console whitespace after user flag`

I found the mention of whitespace after the password flag `-p`, [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html). But the page no where talks about the whitespace after the user flag `-u`.

> ....there must be no space between -p or --password= and the password following it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-p` option takes an optional argument:

```
mysql --help --verbose
...
  -p, --password[=name]
  Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
  not given it's asked from the tty.
```

So, a command line that contains:

```
-p mydb
```

would be ambiguous ... does this means to:

- Prompt the user for a password, and use the `mydb` database ?
- Use the password `mydb`, and not set a default database ?

This is why the documentation insists on a particular rule for the password option: the value, if given, must be attached (no space).

For options that always take an argument, like `-u`, there are no special considerations, so the white space is not significant.

See the manual for a full documentation of command line options:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/command-line-options.html